# count conditional output in foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have foreach loop like this

```
foreach($destinations as $destination)
{
if($destination=="abc")
{
 $msg = "Yes";
}
else
{
 $msg = "No";
}
}
```

How can I count number of "Yes" and "No" generated by "if statement" outside "foreach loop"?

Comment: This question is a joke, right? How can any competent programmer not know how to do this?

Comment: its not a joke, I'm just tired of coding since morning hence my level of thinking is at its lowest now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$yes = 0;
$no = 0;
foreach($destinations as $destination)
{
    if($destination=="abc")
    {
        $yes += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $no += 1;
    }
}

echo "Yes " . $yes . "<br>" . "No " . $no;
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside 'if' statement you can try this

```
    $yesCount = 0;
    $noCount = 0;
    foreach($destinations as $destination)
    {
      if($destination=="abc")
      {
        $yesCount++;
        $msg = "Yes";
      }
      else
      {
        $noCount++;
        $msg = "No";
      }

    }
```

But i am not sure whether it can be used outside.

Answer (score 1):

Create two flag variables and try this

```
$yesFlag=0;
$noFlag=0;
foreach($destinations as $destination)
{
 if($destination=="abc")
 {
  $msg = "Yes";
  $yesFlag++;  
 } 
 else
 {
   $msg = "No";
   $noFlag++;
 }
}
echo "no. of Yes:".yesFlag;
echo "no. of NO:".noFlag;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$yesCount = 0;
$noCount = 0;
    foreach($destinations as $destination) {
        if($destination=="abc") {
            $msg = "Yes";
            $yesCount = $yesCount + 1;
        }
        else {
            $msg = "No";
            $noCount = $noCount + 1;
        }
    }
echo $yesCoynt . " --- " . $noCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

***Just try with the following example :***

```
<?php
$destinations = array('abc','def','ghi');
foreach($destinations as $destination)
{
if($destination=="abc")
{
 $msg = "Yes";
 $msg_yes_counter[]= "I'm in"; 
}
else
{
 $msg = "No";
 $msg_no_counter[]= "I'm in";
}
}
echo "YES -> My Count is :".count($msg_yes_counter);
echo "NO -> My Count is :".count($msg_no_counter);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the array_count_values() function, no need for a loop at all then.

```
array_count_values($destinations);
```

Comment: How does that count the number of `"abc"` elements in `$destinations`?